# React Router and route params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, jsx

I've had a browse and I couldn't find anything solving this for me. I've got a problem with a routing requirement that I've got within my SPA. There is an optional parameter in the middle of a URL. For example, I would like both this:

```
/username/something/overview
```

and

```
/username/overview
```

To resolve to the same thing.

**First Attempt**

I first tried to use the parenthesis to mark this as an optional parameter.

```
<Route path='/:username(/:shard)' component={ProfileContainer}>
  <IndexRoute component={OverviewContainer} />
  <Route component={MatchHistoryContainer} path='/:username/(/:shard)/history' />
  <Route component={DailyTrendsContainer} path='/:username/(/:shard)/trends' />
</Route>
```

However, the outcome of this is that `username/history` resolves to the root, because it thinks 'history' is the value of the `shard` routing parameter. So `username/something/overview` worked with this, but `username/overview` no longer worked.

**Attempt 2**

I took another run at it, by defining a whole new set of routes in the routing definition:

```
<Route path='/:username' component={ProfileContainer}>
  <IndexRoute component={OverviewContainer} />
  <Route component={MatchHistoryContainer} path='/:username/history' />
  <Route component={DailyTrendsContainer} path='/:username/trends' />
  <Route path='/:username/:shard' component={ProfileContainer}>
    <IndexRoute component={OverviewContainer} />
    <Route component={MatchHistoryContainer} path='/:username/:shard/history' />
    <Route component={DailyTrendsContainer} path='/:username/:shard/trends' />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

I put the *history* and *overview* routes above the ones with the optional parameters so that they would resolve first. I then declared the additional routes with the parameter (but this time not marked as optional) so it would resolve to those after it had tried the ones I wanted.

With this approach, *history* and *overview* worked a treat! However, the urls with the `shard` parameter in them no longer worked, and resulted in a loop, because whenever it tried to render out, it failed.

I was wondering if there is an idiom or someone with a little more experience of react router could point out something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can put the optional `params` in the middle of the url, like this way:

```
<Route path='/test' component={Home}>
    <Route path='/test(/:name)/a' component={Child}/>
</Route>
```

don't use the `/` after `test` it will be the optional `params` for Home.

In ur 1st case just remove the `/` after `username`, it should work, try this:

```
<Route path='/:username(/:shard)' component={ProfileContainer}>
  <IndexRoute component={OverviewContainer} />
  <Route component={MatchHistoryContainer} path='/:username(/:shard)/history' />
  <Route component={DailyTrendsContainer} path='/:username(/:shard)/trends' />
</Route>
```

Comment: I am unsure if you are man or God, but you are awesome! Thankyou for spotting my dumb mistake!!

Comment: I spoke far too soon! So this will mean that it works if the optional parameter is there, but it won't work if it's not. i.e /:username/history is still resolving to the root instead of to the HistoryContainer.